# Mostrar solo tipo de dato contenido en vector en R

Tags: r

necesito mostrar solo los datos chr en un vector en R que contiene también números, si alguien podría orientarme como hacerlo se lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: Lo que busco es mostrar variables cualitativas y cuantitativas

Comment: Bienvenido Javier Segura a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Un vector solo puede ser de un determinado tipo de dato, ¿te refieres a mostras los valores que eventualmente no puedan convertirse a numéricos? ¿podrías agregar un ejemplo de este vector que mencionas?

Comment: Perdón, era una tabla de datos no vector. la tabla contiene campos como año los cuales son numéricos y campos los cuales son textos, lo que yo busco hacer es que al mostrar la tabla se muestren solo los datos de un tipo

Answer (score 0):

Voy a resolver este ejercicio utilizando  el siguiente data.frame como ejemplo:

```
#Ejemplo de df con formato de numero y texto
df<-data.frame(dato_chr=sample(c("a","b","c"),10,replace = TRUE),
           dato2_chr=sample(c("a","b","c"),10,replace = TRUE),
           dato3_chr=sample(c("a","b","c"),10,replace = TRUE),
           num_1=sample(c(1,2,3),10,replace = TRUE),
           num_2=sample(c(1,2,3),10,replace = TRUE),
           num_3=sample(c(1,2,3),10,replace = TRUE))

 #Utilizando base R
 #Nos indica si la columna es de tipo chr o no
 tipo_columnas<-sapply(df,function(x) is.character(x))
 df[,tipo_columnas]

    dato_chr dato2_chr dato3_chr
1         a         a         b
2         c         b         c
3         a         b         c
4         c         c         b
5         a         c         a
6         c         b         b
7         b         c         b
8         a         a         a
9         b         b         b
10        c         b         a

#utilizando la libreria dplyr obtendremos el mismo resultado
dplyr::select_if(df, is.character)
```